# How To create a Keyword in robot framework if xpath is the only different

Tags: python, robotframework

Cuurently I'm using

```
${dictionary_data}=  Create Dictionary
    ${column_Count}=  Get Element Count  ${total_columns}
    FOR  ${column_index}  IN RANGE  1  ${column_Count}+1
        ${xpath_available}=  Run Keyword And Ignore Status  Element Should Be Visible  //div[@class='abc']\[${column_index}]/div[1]/div[2] 
        ${webelements}=  Run Keyword If  ${xpath_available}  Get Webelements  //div[@class='abc']\[${column_index}]/div[1]/div[2] 
        @{element_list}  Create List 
        IF  ${xpath_available}
            FOR  ${element}  IN  @{webelement}
                ${element_text}=  Get Text  ${element}
                Append To List  ${element_list}  ${element_text}
            END
        END
        Set To Dictionary  ${dictionary_data}  ${key}=${element_list}
    END
```

this code repeats for every test case only the xpath will vary for each time so i want to use keywords instead of writing this code again and again and also instead of creating the list i want to add element one by one when it is iterating in for loop and add to the dictionary can anyone guide how can i acheive expected result

```
    #ex1
${element_xpath}=  //div[@class='abc']\[${column_index}]/div[1]/div[2]  
#ex2
${element_xpath}=  //div[@class='abc']/div[1]/div[2]\[${column_index}]
```

somewhere in my xpath I’ll have ${column_index}

So only xpath will be different in other test cases so can we create Keyword which will work even if the xpath is different but it contains ${column_index} somewhere in xpath any suggestions how can i do that

Comment: Your examples should work if you use `Set Variable` keyword.

Comment: @Pekka can you show with the code because i tried with Set Variable also and xpath will be different for different test cases it showed error as ${column_index} not found

Comment: Hi, I think I misunderstood your question. If I understood it this time correctly, you want to create a keyword that accepts an XPath which has a RF variable inside. You want to convert this variable to index inside a FOR-loop? This can be done by escaping variable and using `Replace Variables` keyword. If this is correct, I can post a sample code in answers.